# Overlapping labels on pie charts

Tags: vega

I'm trying to replicate a chart, but I can't seem to control my labels.  Any suggestions on replicating this chart in Vega?

[Chart to Replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic1FB.png)

Labels overlapped after adding them-- So I tried adding the label transform, but now they seem a bit scattered. I've tried adjustments, but nothing seems to reign them in.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be nice. Thanks.

[Current Vega Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVVrg.png)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 10,
  "autosize": "none",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {
          "category": "A",
          "amount": 84.64,
          "amountText": "84.64%",
          "col": "#00f"
        },
        {
          "category": "B",
          "amount": 1.5,
          "amountText": "1.50%",
          "col": "#0f0"
        },
        {
          "category": "C",
          "amount": 3.47,
          "amountText": "3.47%",
          "col": "#f00"
        },
        {
          "category": "D",
          "amount": 1.15,
          "amountText": "1.15%",
          "col": "#fa0"
        },
        {
          "category": "E",
          "amount": 3.47,
          "amountText": "3.47%",
          "col": "#0ff"
        },
        {
          "category": "F",
          "amount": 1.15,
          "amountText": "1.15%",
          "col": "#f0f"
        },
        {
          "category": "G",
          "amount": 3.47,
          "amountText": "3.47%",
          "col": "#aaa"
        },
        {
          "category": "H",
          "amount": 1.15,
          "amountText": "1.15%",
          "col": "#000"
        }
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "pie",
          "field": "amount",
          "sort": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
          "name": "pie",
          "type": "arc",
          "from": {
            "data": "table"
          },
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": { "signal": "datum.col"
              },
              "x": {
                "signal": "width / 2"
              },
              "y": {
                "signal": "height / 2"
              },
              "startAngle": {
                "field": "startAngle"
              },
              "endAngle": {
                "field": "endAngle"
              },
              "innerRadius": {
                "value": 0
              },
              "outerRadius": {
                "value": 75
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name":"label",
          "type": "text",
          "from": {
            "data": "pie"
          },
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {
                "signal": "width / 2"
              },
              "y": {
                "signal": "height / 2"
              },
              "radius": {
                "value": 100
              },
              "theta": {
                "signal": "(datum.startAngle + datum.endAngle)/2"
              },
              "fill": {
                "value": "#000"
              },
              "align": {
                "value": "center"
              },
              "baseline": {
                "value": "middle"
              },
              "text": {
                "field": "datum.amountText"
              },
              "ruleStartX": {
                "signal": "(width/2)+80*cos((datum.startAngle + datum.endAngle)/2-(PI/2))"
              },
              "ruleStartY": {
                "signal": "(height/2)+80*sin((datum.startAngle + datum.endAngle)/2-(PI/2))"
              }
            }
          },

      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "avoidMarks": [],
          "avoidBaseMark": false,
          "size": {
            "signal": "[width, height]"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "theta",
          "expr": "datum.theta"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"rule1",
      "type": "rule",
      "from": {
        "data": "label"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter":{
          "x":{"signal":"datum.ruleStartX"},
          "y":{"signal":"datum.ruleStartY"},
          "x2":{"signal": "(datum.bounds.x2-datum.bounds.x1)/2+datum.bounds.x1"},
          "y2":{"signal": "if(datum.bounds.y1>height/2,datum.bounds.y1-5, datum.bounds.y2+5)"},
          "stroke":{"signal": "if(abs(datum.ruleStartY-datum.bounds.y1)>10,'black','white')"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```